# Can I order my questions filtered by tag reverse chronologically?

Tags: support, search

Is this possible?

I'm trying to find a question I asked some time ago, but I guess I've asked too many questions on this topic already, so I'm having trouble finding it.

Also, does the search do a full body search? Sometimes it doesn't pick up questions when I think it should.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Advanced Super Ninja Search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search)

`[TagName] user:me`

then sort by `Newest`

Comment: Oh...see... the problem was that I didn't see the "Newest" tab hidden over there on the right. Tabs seem like an odd convention for ordering.